# Cannot connect to remote port 465

Tags: firewall, smtp

I (actually, not me, rather a friend of mine) have a very strange issue. There's a VPS with CentOS, probably version 5:

`Linux [hostname] 2.6.18-274.7.1.el5xen #1 SMP Thu Oct 20 17:43:28 EDT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

The problem is simple: it's not possible to connect to any outside server's port 465 (smtps).

`# telnet smtp.gmail.com 465

Trying 173.194.69.108...

telnet: connect to address 173.194.69.108: Connection refused

Trying 173.194.69.109...

telnet: connect to address 173.194.69.109: Connection refused

Trying 2a00:1450:4008:c01::6d...`

-- by the way, this happens immediately, it's not a timeout (not somebody silently dropping packets).

What I've tried to turn off the firewall (even with firewall on, there are no signs of blocking that port, there's an ALLOW for outbound TCP connections for 465). It's a VPS, so obviously it might be blocked by the provider but it's highly unlikely as it's possible to connect to the VPS's internal SMTP server from the outside on port 465. Everything seems to be as open as possible, and still, a simple telnet connection is refused immediately.

Any ideas? stunnel is not running, there's an exim instance listening on the local port 465, although that should not matter.

Comment: have you contacted the vps provider?  my guess is they they have a filter blocking all sorts of outbound smtp? Are 25 and 587 blocked outbound.  Try installing tcptraceroute and tcptraceroute to port 465 and see where it dies.

Comment: Not yet, we haven't contacted them. 25 and 587 are not blocked. tcptraceroute shows it can reach 1e100.net, which is a Google server:

`# tcptraceroute -p 465 smtp.gmail.com
traceroute to smtp.gmail.com (173.194.69.109), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  178.21.130.65 (178.21.130.65)  0.336 ms  0.315 ms  0.301 ms
 2  bk-in-f109.1e100.net (173.194.69.109)  158.190 ms  158.174 ms  158.156 ms`

Comment: Had the same problem on a notebook, culprit was the WLAN router blocking port 465.

Answer (score 0):

Use tcptraceroute to locate problem/firewall as (indirectly) suggested by [sz4kerto](https://serverfault.com/users/166692/sz4kerto):

```
tcptraceroute -p 465 smtp.gmail.com
```

Comment: Sorry, sz4kerto (myself) is the one who asked the question :) 
However, we asked the VPS provider, they said they don't block anything AND THEN magically it started to work. Thanks for the tips.